# Compare crm id sdk early bound issue

Tags: c#, linq, dynamics-crm-2011, guid

I try to compare 2 Guid in Linq to Crm request and it's not working. I don't see why:

```cs
Guid IdThematique = new Guid(ddlThematique);
Sollicitations = Sollicitations.Where(i => i.Sollicitation.SubjectId.Id == IdThematique);
```

This is the catched:

> System.NullReferenceException: La référence d'objet n'est pas définie
>   à une instance d'un objet. à XXX dans XXX 74 à
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereListIterator`1.MoveNext() à
>   System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source) à
>   System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`1.d__0.MoveNext() à
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.Count[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source) à xxx dans
>   xxx 200

Thank you

Comment: I don't suppose you have an English translation?

Comment: at least it's not in arabic ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll agree with Mario, but I'd make it an extension method:

More concise version:

```
public static class EntityReferenceExtensions{
    public static Guid GetIdOrDefault(this EntityReference entity){
        return (entity ?? new EntityReference()).Id;
    }
}
```

Arguably more readable version:

```
public static class EntityReferenceExtensions{
    public static Guid GetIdOrDefault(this EntityReference entity){
        if(entity == null){
            return Guid.Empty;
        } else {
            return entity.Id;
        }
    }
}
```

But with the extension method, you could handle any Entity Reference of any Entity object (early or late bound)

```
Sollicitations.Where(i => (i.Sollicitation.SubjectId.GetIdOrDefault() == IdThematique))
```

Although now that I think about it, I don't think that this works for linq to CRM.  Just Linq to Objects.

Comment: from the error looks like he is not using `Linq to CRM` because it will throw a different error instead of a null advice, but without the full code is hard to tell

Comment: @GuidoPreite I'm not up to date on my (I'm guessing that's French) French, so I wasn't quite sure if the error was a Linq to CRM or just a Linq error.  The word "Context" is also missing, so I guess all signs point to this being a collection of objects and my code would work just fine :)

Answer (score 3):

Possibly you have records where Subject is not filled and `i.Sollicitation.SubjectId` is null.

From top of my head, something below should make it work:

```
Sollicitations.Where(i => (i.Sollicitation.SubjectId != null && i.Sollicitation.SubjectId.Id == IdThematique))
```

Answer (score -1):

You are converting ddlThematique to an Guid which is wrong I think. You need to use the Text property from the ddlThematique.